# Elasticsearch search perform cross reference between 2 types

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch index which contains 2 types, 'product' and 'brand'

I have a request to filter out the brands that don't have products are active (`status='active'`).

The product has following fields:

```
brand_uuid
status
name
...
```

The brand has following fields:

```
uuid
name
...
```

So far I am trying my luck:

http://search.localhost:9200/site/brand,product/

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "active"
          }
        },
        *** Don't know how to cross reference between types for the second query ***
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to elasticsearch and have not done this before, is it possible to perform such search?

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent/child relationship between brand (parent) and product(child). Have a look at the 'parent/child' section in this blog post:

http://www.elasticsearch.com/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/

You can then use a '[has_child' filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) that will only return brands where the products' status is `active`.